# Facebook Messenger webhook verification failure with web.api

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, webhooks

I cannot get this working for the life of me.  I'm using Web.API and my verify function looks like:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Webhook()
        {
            string token = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub.verify_token"];
            string challenge = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"];
            string mode = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub.mode"];
            if (token.Equals("rwJsKJqHx7g0"))
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(challenge)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("")
                };
            }
        }
```

The route looks like this:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Calling it manually like:

https://host/site/ControllerName?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1234&hub.verify_token=rwJsKJqHx7g0

Returns 1234 in plain text, as you'd expect.

The host has a valid SSL certificate currently in use.

I've run this locally via ngrok and the URL works as I'd expect,  passing through when I do it manually but when trying to add the hook in FB it doesn't even hit.

Error is "The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later."

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying your app to some legit host like AWS, heroku etc.
I think ngrok no longer works in this case due to some security steps they added to prevent abuse